# how to bind something to a function in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, upshot

I am using knockout.js and upshot.js to get a list of items from API controller on the server. This is basically my view model:

```
self.templatesDataSource = upshot.dataSources.Templates.refresh();
self.templates = self.templatesDataSource.getEntities();
```

Binding to properties works just fine:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: templates">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: Title"></a><br />
</div>
```

But let's say I want the text to not only display the title, but a combination of the title and some other value? Let's say I want `Title + ' ' + Id`. Based on "example 4" from [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), I'm thinking I should be able to do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: templates">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: function(item){return item.Title + ' ' + item.Id; }"></a><br />
</div>
```

However, I see the function text (`function(item){...`etc) instead of result. I would also need this functionality to construct proper href for the link. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just write your statement directly like:

```
data-bind="text: Title + " " + Id"
```

If your properties are observables, then you would do:

```
data-bind="text: Title() + " " + Id()"
```

For binding against `href` you would do:

```
data-bind="attr: { href: Url }"
```

The other option when you are calculating a value is to use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to represent the value.

Comment: data-bind="text: Title + ' ' + Id" resulted in a long compressed javascript function as output. However, using data-bind="text: Title() + ' ' + Id()" produced desired result. Whatever upshot.js returns as datasource is indeed observable. Thank you!!!